# HTML and AJAX - web service output not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web-services

I am trying to invoke a web service (written with Flask) from a HTML page, using AJAX and JavaScript. The web service is getting called and executed successfully and I can see the outputs I printed on STDOUT. The control is going inside AJAX `success` function as well. However, the outputs from response of web service are not showing up on browser.

Here's my HTML file.

```html
<!-- include ajax -->
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- form, button and output -->
<center>
<input type="text" id="input" name="input" size="50" placeholder="Enter input"/>
<button id="btn">Click</button>

<div id="api_input"> Input </div>
<div id="api_output"> Output </div>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function api_call(input) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api",
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(input),
            success: function( data, jQxhr ){
        $("#api_input").html( data.input );
        $("#api_output").html( data.output );
        $("#input").val("");
            },
            error: function( jqXhr, errorThrown ){
                $("#api_output").html( "There was an error" );
                console.log( errorThrown );
            },
            timeout: 10000
        });
    }
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // request when clicking on the button
        $('#btn').click(function() {
            // get the input data
            var input = $("#input").val();
            api_call(input);
            input = "";
        });
    });
</script>
```

I know that the web service call is successful because `$("#input").val("");` is being executed and the input is reset, however `api_input` and `api_output` remains unchanged.

I am absolute beginner to these techs, so I'm sure that I'm doing something very silly somewhere. So, any help is welcome :)

Comment: Put a `console.log(data)` as the first line of the success handler. Let us know what that looks like.

Comment: What is your environment? Hosted VSP? XAMPP? Shared hosting account with CPANEL and Passenger?

Comment: Thank you @RandyCasburn for the suggestion. After looking at console log, I realized that I hadn't `jsonify()`-ed the `response` from my Flask app properly. After fixing that, it is working fine now. Thank you so much for the pointer!

Comment: Hi @cssyphus, I was running the Flask app locally. Anyways, as mentioned above, now the issue is resolved. Thank you for your time in looking into this.